# What is the Theme name of selected text in Visual Studio (2015)

Tags: visual-studio

I want to change the colour of selected text in Visual Studio but I cannot find out the name its under in themes ?

[image: left mouse down over code]

Can you see it ? Its the dark navy colour that I want to change, I can't see code to well when its selected

Comment: try to research that link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320853/change-text-color-for-selected-text-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out..
Go to Tools->Options(at the bottom)->Environment->Fonts and colors
On the right hand side of the menu find the selected Text option and change the item background as you like

Comment: Thats it ! Thanks.  I was using a Theme editor (Son of Obsidian) and I got the Hex value (14184c) but I couldn't find it.  Changing background color in selected text did it !